# How do I read data from a list in python that isn't recognised as a list

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to create some scripts to essentially just rip some JSON data from API connections to CSV.
The particular JSON I am working with is nested a few layers deep and I have been trying to step through it 1 layer at a time so that I learn and understand the concepts (which I have been picking up from various posts etc.) but I have managed to get so far down and stuck at the last hurdle where I end up with a string that is essentially a list but isn't being recognised as one when I try and query it.

The string ends up like this (as variable col_data):
"[{'value': 'Checking', 'id': '35'}, {'value': '1201.00'}, {'value': ''}]"

My assumption is that it is not recognised as a list because the "{}" sections are not enclosed with double quotes.

I am trying to get to a point where I can query each of the respective values to produce a CSV file:
`val1 = col_data[0][value]`

The whole thing is recognised as a single item in a list, as opposed to the 3 items I would like.

I'm also aware the problem probably lies further up the stack with how I broke the original JSON response down to this point:

```py
data = response.json()
rows = [('Account', 'Debit', 'Credit')]
row_data = data['Rows']['Row']

x = 0
for row in row_data:
    rowx_data = row_data[x]
    col_data = [rowx_data.get('ColData')]
    col_data = col_data[0]
    row = (
        col_data,
        'test',
        'test'
    )
    rows.append(row)
    x = x + 1
```

The original response looked liked below and I was only interested in the content of the rows:

```json
{
  "Header": {
    "Time": "2023-06-12T13:55:49-07:00",
    "ReportName": "TrialBalance",
    "DateMacro": "this month-to-date",
    "ReportBasis": "Accrual",
    "StartPeriod": "2023-06-01",
    "EndPeriod": "2023-06-12",
    "SummarizeColumnsBy": "Total",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "Option": [
      {
        "Name": "NoReportData",
        "Value": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Columns": {
    "Column": [
      {
        "ColTitle": "",
        "ColType": "Account"
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Debit",
        "ColType": "Money"
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Credit",
        "ColType": "Money"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Rows": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Checking",
            "id": "35"
          },
          {
            "value": "1201.00"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Savings",
            "id": "36"
          },
          {
            "value": "800.00"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Accounts Receivable (A/R)",
            "id": "84"
          },
          {
            "value": "5281.52"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Inventory Asset",
            "id": "81"
          },
          {
            "value": "596.25"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Undeposited Funds",
            "id": "4"
          },
          {
            "value": "2062.52"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Truck:Original Cost",
            "id": "38"
          },
          {
            "value": "13495.00"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Accounts Payable (A/P)",
            "id": "33"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "1602.67"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Mastercard",
            "id": "41"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "157.72"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Arizona Dept. of Revenue Payable",
            "id": "89"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "0.00"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Board of Equalization Payable",
            "id": "90"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "370.94"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Loan Payable",
            "id": "43"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "4000.00"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Notes Payable",
            "id": "44"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "25000.00"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Opening Balance Equity",
            "id": "34"
          },
          {
            "value": "9337.50"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "Retained Earnings",
            "id": "2"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "1642.46"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "TOTAL"
            },
            {
              "value": "32773.79"
            },
            {
              "value": "32773.79"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "GrandTotal"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, running your code as-is suggests that you've just missed the fact that your `col_data` variable actually contains a list of lists. Try this:

```py
data = load_json('test.json')
rows = [('Account', 'Debit', 'Credit')]
row_data = data['Rows']['Row']

x = 0
for row in row_data:
    rowx_data = row_data[x]
    col_data = [rowx_data.get('ColData')]
    col_data = col_data[0]
    if col_data is not None:
        row = (
            col_data[0].get('value'),
            col_data[1].get('value'),
            col_data[2].get('value')
        )
        rows.append(row)
    x = x + 1
```

Output:

```py
[('Account', 'Debit', 'Credit'),
 ('Checking', '1201.00', ''),
 ('Savings', '800.00', ''),
 ('Accounts Receivable (A/R)', '5281.52', ''),
 ('Inventory Asset', '596.25', ''),
 ('Undeposited Funds', '2062.52', ''),
 ('Truck:Original Cost', '13495.00', ''),
 ('Accounts Payable (A/P)', '', '1602.67'),
 ('Mastercard', '', '157.72'),
 ('Arizona Dept. of Revenue Payable', '', '0.00'),
 ('Board of Equalization Payable', '', '370.94'),
 ('Loan Payable', '', '4000.00'),
 ('Notes Payable', '', '25000.00'),
 ('Opening Balance Equity', '9337.50', ''),
 ('Retained Earnings', '', '1642.46')]
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, this worked perfectly. My brain was starting to hurt - I was certain i had tried something along those lines but had been going in circles. Your code also made me realise that the col_data[0] section was pointless as I only needed it because I had made it a list with the [] above; so I got rid of a couple of a line there as well.

Answer (score -1):

simple quote `'` is not valid in json. You need double quotes `''`.
So, that string is not json formatted. You need to reformat to json and read it:

```py
import json
s = "[{'value': 'Checking', 'id': '35'}, {'value': '1201.00'}, {'value': ''}]".replace("\'", "\"")

s = json.loads(s)

type(s)
# output: list

s
# output: [{'value': 'Checking', 'id': '35'}, {'value': '1201.00'}, {'value': ''}]
```

You might need extra tweaks if you have single quotes that you want to keep, etc., but this would be a good starting point.

Comment: I ended up going with PangolinaPaws solution but thankyou for the code here as I had tried something similar previously but ended up with 2 double quotes instead of 1; your code helped me realise I needed to escape the quote with the slash character - so I will now remember that one in the future!